# Move snap's multi-GB subdir "/var/lib/snapd/snaps" to different partition, then symlink to it?

Tags: 20.04, snap

I have "only" a 64 Gigabyte root partition, `/`, hence implicitly the `/var` dir is on this partition, and so is  snap's multi-GB subdir `/var/lib/snapd/snaps` . Snap stores the snap images in this directory. This takes quite some disk space.

I have freshly installed these snaps: `boxy-svg, core, core18, core20, core22, eclipse, fx, gnome-3-34-1804, gnome-3-38-2004, go, gtk-common-themes, inkscape, minizinc, postman, powershell, rustup, slack, snapd, tidy, youtube-dl, zoom-client`, and they already need 2,7G for a single-instance install. For backups this will increase to 10 GB quickly, because snap stores images of the 2 previous images too, in the long run.

I want to move these 10 GB on `/var/lib/snapd/snaps` to a different partition, on a different SSD. How can I do that properly?

I've tried by

1. just by stopping snapd with `sysctl`,
2. move `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`
   to a different partition
3. symlinking to that partition `ln -s  /mnt/big-disk/snaps /var/lib/snapd/snaps`
   1, restart snapd

However, this construct does not "survive" reboots (snaps cannot be mounted during startup), and also the snaps cannot be updated easily. As a workaround I've tried scripting commands such as
`mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/inkscape_10426.snap           /snap/inkscape/10426`
(with `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` being a symlink),
but these are a nightmare to maintain, because the release ids such as `10426` always change.

Comment: I've never tried it so far, but I'd recommend to mount the dedicated partition via `/etc/fstab` instead of using a symlink. There is another big directory `/var/lib/snapd/cache`, so you should move the whole `/var/lib/snapd` to  a dedicated partition. I'd written an answer, but, as I said, I never tried it.

Comment: Linking out snaps will very likely work, mounting it on a dedicated partition, or mount --binding it to some other directory via fstab, will definitely work.